# What exactly does the state "ic" in dpkg mean?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I know how to read the status in `dpkg -l` (first letter is desired state, second is actual state). For example `ii` means "should be installed and actually is installed" and `rc` means "should be removed but config files are still there".

For me these `ic` packages are `example-content`, `pppconfig`, `pppoeconf` and `unity-lens-applications` (I'm on Ubuntu 19.10).

But what exactly does `ic` mean? Formally it means it is installed, but only the configuration files are there. Why does `apt-get` not install/fix the packages if they are not `ii`? How do I interpret this state? Should I do something about this?

Or do these packages only consist of configuration files? (shouldn't they still have `ii` then because they are installed correctly?)

Answer (score 1):

From [dpkg, letters in column on the left](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/dpkg-letters-in-column-on-the-left-366316/):

> `ic` = (*this is a tough one*) I don't really know but I'd guess that
>   you've asked dpkg to install this package but something went wrong and
>   currently only its config files are installed -- reinstalling the
>   package might help